# Preciso que um mesmo formulário com 2 botões enviem para locais diferente

Tags: php, javascript, html

Boa noite galera, estou com um pequeno problema tenho um **foreach** que carrega varios cards em uma pagina, cada card possui um modal com as respectivas informações do card, *Os modais são Carregados da mesma maneira que o card* , preciso que um dos botoes atualize as informações do paciente e que outro de um delete(*Botão de Alta*) eles funcionavam quando os cards eram fixos mas depois que colequei dinamicos na pagina as os botoes não funcionaram mais, tente trocar as id,valor,name, mas nada adiantou,alguem pode me ajudar?

seguem o codigo do JS usado anteriomente para alterar o modar e Segue tbm o codigo do formulario do modal

```js
$(document).on('click', '#alterar', function() {
    $(this).attr("id","salvar").html("Salvar");
    $(this).attr("onclick","myFunction()").html("Salvar");
});
$(document).on('click', '#salvar', function() {
    $(this).attr("id","alterar").html("Alterar");
    $(this).attr("type","submit").html("Salvar");
    $(this).attr("value","enviar").html("Salvar");

});
   $(document).on('click', id, function () {
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
        document.dadosPaciente.action = "formsDB/Delete.php";
        document.dadosPaciente.submit();

    });



function disableField() {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
}

function undisableFieldset() {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}

function HabCampos() {
    if (document.getElementById('medico').checked) {
        document.getElementById('form_medico').style.display = "";
        document.getElementById('form_enfermeiro').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('text').focus();

    }  if (document.getElementById('enfermeiro').checked){
        document.getElementById('form_medico').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('form_enfermeiro').style.display = "";
        document.getElementById('text').focus();
    }}

function desabilita_a(){

    document.getElementById('form_enfermeiro').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('form_medico').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
      <!-- Inicio Modal view/update paciente -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content mb-0">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="modalViewTitle">Visualisar paciente </h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mb-0">
              <form id="dadosPaciente" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="dadosPaciente" method="post">
                    <fieldset id="camada" disabled>
                        Numero do Paciente :<br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numero_paciente" value="'.$resultado[$i]['numero_paciente'].'" readonly/>
                        <br>Nome do paciente:<br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome_paciente" value="'.$resultado[$i]['nome_paciente'].'" readonly/>
                        <br>Data de Internação :<br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="dtInter_paciente" value="'.$resultado[$i]['dtInter_paciente'].'" readonly/>
                        <br>Tempo de gravidez: <br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="dtParto_paciente"
                              placeholder="'.$resultado[$i]['dtParto_paciente'].' semanas"/>
                        <br>Classificação de Robson: <br>
                        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-1" name="clasRob">
                            <option value="">'.$rob.'</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <br>Tipo Internação : (Anteparto, Parto, Pós-parto)<br>
                        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-1" name="TipoInter">
                            <option value="">{TIPOPARTOMODAL0}</option>
                            <option value="Anteparto">Anteparto</option>
                            <option value="Parto">Parto</option>
                            <option value="pos">Pós-Parto</option>
                        </select>
                        <br><br>Admissão obstétrica (TP espontâneo, TP induzido, Sem TP)<br>
                        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-1" name="adimis">
                            <option value="{TP0}"></option>
                            <option value="Espontâneo">Espontâneo</option>
                            <option value="Induzido">Induzido</option>
                            <option value="Sem TP">Sem Tp</option>
                        </select>
                        <br><br>Risco Gestacional (risco habitual e alto risco)<br>
                        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-1" name="risco">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Habitual">Habitual</option>
                            <option value="Alto Risco">Alto Risco</option>
                        </select>
                        <br><br>Transfusão (sim ou não)<br>
                        <label for="sim">Sim</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="tranfu" id="sim" value="Sim" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <label for="não">Não</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="tranfu" id="não" value="Não" />
                        <br><br>Evento adverso (se teve ou não - detalhar)<br>
                        <font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( Limite de 1000 caracteres. )<br>
                            <textarea class="form-control" wrap="physical" name="message" rows="5" cols="30"
                                      onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,1000);"
                                      onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,1000);"></textarea>
                            faltam&nbsp;<input readonly type=text name=remLen size=1 maxlength=1 value="1000"
                                               style="border: none;width: 30px;"><br></font><br>
                    </fieldset>
                        <div class="modal-footer mb-0">
                          <button type="button" value="alta" id="alta" class="float-left btn btn-success">Alta
                          </button>
                            <button onclick="disableField()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                    data-dismiss="modal">Fechar
                            </button>
                            <button onclick="undisableFieldset();" value="up" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    id="alterar">Alterar</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim Modal view/update paciente -->
```

Comment: Essa variável `id` nesta linha: `$(document).on('click', id, function () {` é o que?

Comment: foi um tentativa que fiz, antes era "alta" e nesse document.getElementById(id).disabled = true; ficava "camada" no lugar do id pois o formulario quando o modal abre ele não fica editavel para o update é necessario que o usuario click no botão alterar para habilitar os campos que pode ser editados.

Comment: Como você disse que são várias modais, um dos erros é usar o mesmo `id` -> `modalView`.